# TV show, late 70s early 80s, two investigators searching for "unknowns"

Tags: tv, episode-identification

I recall a US series from the late 1970s (possibly early 80s) that involved two protagonists (brothers?) who investigate science mysteries/paranormal. I only saw one episode and never saw the end, so I'd like to find it and watch the end decades later.

The episode took place in a hospital. A patient has mysterious problems that the doctors dismiss and the two are investigating what was going on. I recall two scenes in particular:

In one, an x-ray machine makes a whole-body scan of the patient - it was mounted in the air above the bed and motorized to make a random orbital motion that was rather distinctive. We then see the two positioning the resulting photos to produce an image of a large oval object surrounding the patient. Spooky!

The second scene is from slightly later. The door to the patient's room is closed, and as the two watch from a safe distance up the hall, the door begins to rattle as something tries to get out. It eventually bursts open and there's... nothing! This scared the willies out of me.

It was definitely a well-known show at the time. I'm pretty sure this pre-dated *Probe* and none of the episode capsules for that show are similar, and I don't think it was the Hardy Boys of that era.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just read the capsule reviews for Hardy Boys. Definitely not there.

Comment: Was it possibly Project U.F.O, which was broadcast in 1978-1979? I vaguely remember a few episodes; not specifically the scene you mentioned, but the description of the show seems to line up with what you remember. Wiki article here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_U.F.O.

Comment: Your description of events sounds just like the sort of thing you could expect to see in an episode of the [1985 version of The Twilight Zone](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088634/) or the [1995 version of The Outer Limits](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112111/), but the time frame you stated would predate both of these shows (certainly Outer Limits).

Comment: @JohnWinkelman - Project UFO, as the name implies, was about UFOs. It was also B&W, which this show was not.

Comment: @AnthonyX - those shows were anthologies, this wasn't, it was following the two main characters from show to show. Ahh, there 1990s OL, *so* low budget!

Comment: @Maury Markowitz Project UFO was in color.   https://www.google.com/search?q=project+ufo&source=lmns&tbm=vid&bih=969&biw=1920&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjBwvK6nIz6AhUUtXIEHZ6tDTIQ_AUoAXoECAEQAQ

Comment: @M.A.Golding - perhaps I am thinking of a different show? I am thinking of one where two air force guys fly around the country (in a T-33 no less) investigating UFO reports.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz If I understand your earlier comment correctly, the show you are trying to identify was B&W? If so, it would have been produced not later than the mid 60s. Few if any shows would have been shot in B&W beyond about 1965. If seen in late 70s to early 80s, you were almost certainly watching a rerun of a show from more than a decade earlier.

Comment: @AnthonyX - No, the show in question was in color. The B&W reference is to the other show that I was familiar with, Project UFO. I guess I just happened to watch that show on B&W TVs.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Project UFO (1978) (starring Edward Winter) was color. Despite the format of Project UFO conforming loosely to your description, and the time frame lining up, I'd be surprised if it turns out to be the show you saw. Project UFO was based on the real-world USAF Project Blue Book and a number of episodes were based on real UFO reports (all of which can be explained without invoking extraterrestrial encounters). According to Wikipedia, however, the series' second season format changed to include "twist" endings suggesting supernatural or extraterrestrial causes behind each case.

Comment: @AnthonyX - that's what I said. The show I am trying to identify is absolutely not Project UFO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The show is *[Kolchak: The Night Stalker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolchak:_The_Night_Stalker)*, the episode is "The Energy Eater". Its up in parts on YT and the x-ray scene I recall is found in the 3rd part, about half way through.

Interestingly, the show has only one protagonist. This particular episode is commented on as it is the only one where there is a second main protagonist, which is why I thought that was the format.

Finally saw the end... not at all what I expected.

Comment: I remember that series, but only vaguely... only thing that stands out to me was Darrin McGavin and the weirdness of the monsters he chased every week.